# Prove the inequality $\frac{a^2+1}{b+c}+\frac{b^2+1}{a+c}+\frac{c^2+1}{a+b}\ge 3$

Tags: inequality

> If $a,b,c\in\mathbb R^+$ prove that:
>    $$\frac{a^2+1}{b+c}+\frac{b^2+1}{a+c}+\frac{c^2+1}{a+b}\ge 3$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply Am-GM to the numerator of each fraction.

You get the statement of Nesbit inequality.

Answer (score 1):

By Cauchy Schwarz Lemma:
$$\frac{a^2}{b+c}+\frac{b^2}{a+c}+\frac{c^2}{a+b}\geqslant \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{2(a+b+c)}$$

Also By $HM\leqslant AM$

$$\frac 3 {\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{a+c}}\leqslant \frac{2(a+b+c)}{3}$$

$$\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{a+c}\geqslant\frac9 {2(a+b+c)}$$

Add both of them. Then apply $AM\geqslant GM$ on RHS

Answer (score 0):

By C-S and AM-GM we obtain
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2+1}{b+c}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b+c}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{b+c}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{2(a+b+c)}+\frac{9}{2(a+b+c)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(a+b+c+\frac{9}{a+b+c}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{2}\cdot2\sqrt{\frac{9(a+b+c)}{a+b+c}}=3.$$
Done!